# Por que mesmo definido os headers o cache da página não é atualizado?

Tags: php, cache, http-headers

Uso o `Laravel 3` em um determinado sistema que desenvolvemos aqui na empresa.

Preciso que, em toda vez que a versão do aplicativo muda, o cache de todos os usuários sejam atualizados.

Os programadores aqui já quiseram utilizar aquela velha tatica de colocar uma interrogação na frente das urls dos `css` e `js`, porém isso é fora de mão, pois são muitos estilos utilizados.

Tive a ideia de definir os header que removem o cache (todo mundo por aí fala que isso funciona), que apareceriam apenas quando o aplicativo fosse atualizado para o usuário.

O problema é que foi constatado que isso não funcionou em nenhum dos testes realizados.

O código que tenho é o seguinte:

```
Route::filter('after', function ($response)
{
    $headers = $response->foundation->headers;

    $version = Config::get('application.version');

    $headers->set('X-App-Version', $version);

    if (Cookie::get('version') != $version || Config::get('error.detail') == true) {

        $headers->addCacheControlDirective('no-cache', true);
        $headers->addCacheControlDirective('max-age', 0);
        $headers->addCacheControlDirective('must-revalidate', true);
        $headers->addCacheControlDirective('no-store', true);

        Cookie::forever('version', $version, URI::current());
    }

});
```

Isso adiciona os seguinte headers:

```
Cache-Control:max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store, private
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:37316
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Mon, 19 Oct 2015 11:20:08 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=38
Server:Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Set-Cookie:version=a5b7217bab8d25e470fa89b6301b6bbe06f9f96e%2B4.5; expires=Sat, 17-Oct-2020 11:20:08 GMT; Max-Age=157679999; path=beneficiario/novidades; httponly
Set-Cookie:nome_do_cookie=03198b561773a09d98d02491766970391b1d8e71%2BWwwUrV5Z94PdQcmKBDMDxpOvjFyfK1NvFp1l4PTQ; path=/; httponly
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-App-Version:4.5
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11
```

Até onde eu sei, isso deveria funcionar para que todo o cache do navegador fosse resetado.

Afinal, existe algum erro no meu código, ou realmente essa definição de headers para definir se o conteúdo vai ter o cache de browser ou não varia de navegador para navegador?

Comment: é para atualizar o cache de arquivos css e js? Não entendi a dificuldade ou empecilho em usar o parâmetro argumentador (?)

Comment: @DanielOmine, simplesmente não tem como! São vários templates, várias views, são vários css e js. Não há maneira de executar isso. E vamos concordar que isso é gambiarra! Para desenvolvimento até vai, mas para produção não concordo não.

Comment: @DanielOmine, eu entendo. Digo que é gambiarra por que que definir um a um! To quase pensando em mudar o codigo fonte do laravel (mais gambiarra ainda) para que isso já seja implementado automaticamente. Ou criar uma função através da macro, que faça isso. É uma idéia a se pensar. Mesmo assim mantenho a pergunta, pois quero saber o motivo de hora funcionar, hora não.

Comment: Não lido com Laravel, mas acredito que no Laravel deve ter os helpers para tal. Todo framework deve ter um recurso desse tipo. Mas se já montou fora do helper HTML apropriado, não tem jeito, vai ter que refazer tudo na unha rsrsrr.. Bom que já vai corrigindo e fazendo com algum helper, se existir no Laravel

Comment: Existe a `macro` @DanielOmine. Com as macros posso criar um método mágico dentro da classe em tempo de execução. Daí uso ela, ao invés de usar a padrão.

Comment: http://laravel.io/forum/03-11-2014-any-l4-mechanism-to-assist-with-version-of-css-js?page=1

Comment: @DanielOmine, exatamente o que estou lendo agora.

Comment: também pode tentar usar url rewrite, onde tudo que for .css e .js seria sobrescrito adicionando o argumentador.. De certa forma fica invisível ao usuário. Só o compilador do browser que enxerga. Mas aí nesse ponto, apesar de ser limpo e elegante, é uma gambiarra e bem grosseira. rsrs mas funciona.